# Magento website get distorted and page elements gets scattered frequently

Tags: javascript, css, magento

I have been working on a magento website which works fine but sometimes after making changes , I reload website the CSS, JS doesnt get loaded and all elements gets scattered and website becomes messy. After cache flush and many reloads , website starts working fine again.
I was using CSS and JS merging option but now I disabled it but still , I am facing this error.
Did anyone here ever face such error before? Or any idea how to solve this bug? I am really stuck over it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS and JS files get stuck in the **browser** cache until they're forcibly flushed.

CTL-F5 page reload for development to view changes or hunt down the browser cache clear function.

If you're doing these changes on your live website, your customers are going to hate it. Use a dev site to test all the changes until completely correct before you commit the change to the live site.

It's not a bug, it's a feature of persistent browser caching.

Several QAs pertinent to the problem

[Force refresh of cached CSS data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870726/force-refresh-of-cached-data)

[How to force flush CSS cache on client side?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-to-force-flush-css-cache-on-client-side)

[How can I force clients to refresh JavaScript files?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60/how-to-force-flush-css-cache-on-client-side)

Comment: Thanks for the appropriate links.