# Delete file still showing on refresh but not on ctrl+F5

Tags: php, html

I have deleted file on server. When I refresh page it is still showing file but when I press ctrl+F5, it gives 404 error.
It should show 404 error on simple refresh. Why it is not showing this error?
Is it any kind of server caching. I've contacted server administration, but no caching is used in server. 
Thanx!

Comment: Client side caching

Comment: Possible solution: [Force refresh of cached CSS data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870726/force-refresh-of-cached-css-data)

Answer (score 0):

its showing just because of your browser cache... you clear your browser cache then you will not see it..

When any web pages loded into your browsers then some info like image are localy stored which browsers shows you... so you clear your cache

Comment: I have cleared my browser cache but same problem. And I have tried different browsers, but same problem in all of them.

Comment: is it still showing from your browser after you deleted files from server? Maybe that files are not deleted and are hidden on your server

Comment: then this means that files are still on server and are hidden or may not deleted...

Comment: Dear this means it deleted from server... 404 mean file not found.